# Raspberry Pi Boot-up Error

Tags: operating-systems

how can i solve this kind of error on raspberry pi. I'm using a modified version of raspbian OS. For some certain purposes i tried to use this mod name Honeeepi (https://redmine.honeynet.org/projects/honeeepi/wiki) in which dionaea is installed.

Before the login prompt a certain failure message at the end of the bootup phase of the OS appeared. Based on what I currently understand motd stands for message of the day. Knowing what does the raspbian os motd displays I noticed that the honeeepi mod doesn't display anything instead it displayed a fail message specifically like this.

"[FAIL ]startpar: service(s) returned failure: motd … failed!"

Comment: might be a good idea to boot up from the known-good image, like raspbian, check if your hardware works well, and only then proceed to the more obscure versions.

Answer (score 1):

Mount the SD card on a computer capable of reading the second partition (i.e., not windows) and have a look in `/var/log`.

Since the pi does not have a real-time clock, and most likely it did not get a network time source before the boot failed, it will be impossible to tell by looking at the modification times of the logs or the timestamps inside what information, if any,<sup>1</sup> is relevant. If the rsyslog configuration is unchanged from raspbian, `/var/log/syslog` should contain everything.

If looking through this does not provide you with any clues, copy the files out so you can try booting the pi again and then compare the subsequent logs to the copy.

---

<sup>1. The system may not have gotten the root filesystem mounted read-write, in which case there will be nothing in the logs.</sup>